# How to get cell address of maximum value by passing specific comma separated cell address?

Tags: excel

How to get cell address of maximum value by passing specific comma separated cell address ?

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but your question is not clear to me. Please try to provide additional detail (what does your Excel sheet look like, what kind of data are you passing, ...).

Comment: From what are you querying? is this a programming question?

Comment: Hi Germi , i am passing  G34,L34,Q34,V34   in that cell have value now i want to get cell address of maximum value .

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following *UDF*:

```
Public Function WhereIsMax(sIN As String) As String
   Dim mx As Variant, wf As WorksheetFunction
   Dim rng As Range, r As Range

   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Set rng = Range(sIN)

   mx = wf.Max(rng)
   For Each r In rng
      If r.Value = mx Then
         WhereIsMax = r.Address(0, 0)
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next r
End Function
```

Just put the comma separated list in some cell and then reference it:

[image]

*NOTE:*

The UDF would need a little tweak if you want to place the input list **within** the UDF.